# Handling Email Verification Response When Email is not verified

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

In a laravel 5.8 API application, I want to pass the response message returned when a user has not verified their email address. To do this, I have added a the code below to the `render` method of the `Handle.php` like this

```
if (
    !$request->user() || ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
        !$request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())
) {
    return response()->json([
        'responseMessage'   => 'Your email address is not verified.',
        'responseStatus'    => 400
    ]);
}
```

Then I have added the middleware to the following route in `api.php` like this

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {

    Route::get('products/{product}', 'ProductController@show')->middleware('verified'); // #1

    Route::get('user', 'UserController@profile')->middleware('verified'); // #2

}
```

## 1 returns the message I want like this

```
{
    "responseMessage": "Your email address is not verified.",
    "responseStatus": 400
}
```

## 2 return something different like this

```
{
    "message": "Your email address is not verified.",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
    "file": "C:\\Users\\Elomena\\Projects\\Clients\\Pramopro\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php",
    "line": 995,
    "trace": [
        {
            ...
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: The 2nd way is the way to go. If you're concerned about the stacktrace that's only shown if the app is in debug mode

Comment: @apokryfos setting `APP_DEBUG` to false removes stacktrace but leaves me with two different types of messages.